# How to use a function as a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, push

I'm trying to use a function as a string right now and it doesn't seem that it's possible. To give you an example of what I mean take a look at the file below:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test Webpage</title>
<div id = "storyDisplay"></div>
<script>
var story = [];
var dangerElements = ["test1","test2","test3"];
function danger () {
    story.push(dangerElements[Math.round(Math.random()*dangerElements.length)];
    document.getElementById("storyDisplay").innerHTML = story.join("");
}

</script>
</html>
```

---

Now when I try to input this code it comes out as:

---

---

Basically, there's no output. I checked the file and it doesn't seem like there's a syntax error, so what's happening?

[EDIT] Sorry, whoops, forgot to add in this part. I want to use danger() like this:

```
var genStory = [danger()];
```

and I want it to output as a random string in story.

Comment: I can see a syntax error. Open your console (hit F12 on Windows or Opt + Cmd + I on Mac) and it will tell you what it is. Word to the wise: indent your code correctly. It will make debugging *way* easier in the future.

Comment: Additionally, you should use `Math.floor` not `Math.round` when computing a random element in an array like that. `Math.round` will occasionally give you an index out of bounds error when it rounds *up* beyond the range of the array.

Comment: What does "use a function as a string" mean? You're just trying to call the function, not use it as something special.

Comment: I suggest you get yourself a good programming editor, it will highlight trivial syntax errors like this.

Comment: @Barmar - he was stringing us along thinking it was an interesting question.

Comment: well kids that's not true at all: the op corrected the syntax error - and by correcting it, didn't get any result, because the syntax error from the code posted was not the cause. See the answer and learn to read the code and the question with your own eyes because the code highlighter is not going to do that for you.

Comment: `danger()` doesn't return anything, what do you expect `[danger()]` to put in the `genStory` array?

Comment: Your parentheses still aren't balanced. Look at the Javascript console for the syntax error.

Comment: After fixing the syntax error, your code works, see https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ysc8k98n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```js
var genStory = [(danger)()];
alert( genStory );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test Webpage</title>
<div id = "storyDisplay"></div>
<script>
var story = [];
var dangerElements = ["test1","test2","test3"];
function danger () {
    story.push(dangerElements[Math.round(Math.random()*dangerElements.length)]);
    return document.getElementById("storyDisplay").innerHTML = story.join("");
}

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were just missing a square bracket and closing parenthesis on line 9

```
story.push(dangerElements[Math.round(Math.random()*dangerElements.length)]);
```

Comment: I fixed the square brackets but it's still not working.